# Can I run 2 different scripts at the same time?

Tags: python

I have two scripts. One of them checks out an online database and the other one checks a telegram bot. Both of them run in loop, but they take some time to check the updates, so I'd like to run them separately. Can I do that?

Comment: Duplicate of [How can I use threading in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846653/how-can-i-use-threading-in-python)

Comment: yes you can, you can either start both script manually for separate or you can run the both with any of the concurrent mechanism available such a threads of multiprocesses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. Use [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) as suggested:

```py
from threading import Thread

def one():
    ...

def two():
    ...

Thread(target=one).start()
Thread(target=two).start()
```